# ts: 'Props' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to another type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

```
const withFirebase = <Props extends {firebase: Firebase}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
): ComponentType<Omit<Props, "firebase">> => (props) => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {(firebase) => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);

export default withFirebase;
```

Here

```
<Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />
```

Throws the below typescript error

```
Type 'Pick<Props, Exclude<keyof Props, "firebase">> & { firebase: Firebase | null; children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'Pick<Props, Exclude<keyof Props, "firebase">> & { firebase: Firebase | null; children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'Props'.
    'Props' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Pick<Props, Exclude<keyof Props, "firebase">> & { firebase: Firebase | null; children?: ReactNode; }
```

Omit<Props, "firebase"> is added to avoid the required prop error in the Wrapped component import.

like

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ItemWithFirebase /> // If not omit is available this will throw prop firebase not available error
  )
}

const Item: FC<{firebase: Firebase}> = ({firebase}) => {
...
}

const ItemWithFirebase = withFirebase(Item);
```

I have casted the spread props as below

```
<Component {...(props as Props)} firebase={firebase} />}
```

But I am not sure if I am doing it right. Could you please let me know if there are any other way to tackle this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes up all the time when writing HOCs.  You're looking at the error and it says "We take `Props`, we remove `Props['firebase']`, we add `{firebase: Firebase | null}`, and we're not sure if this object is assignable to `Props`".  You might think, "if I removed `firebase` and then added it back, of course that's the same thing".  *Technically*, `Props extends {firebase: Firebase}` means that `Props['firebase']` could be something more specific than `Firebase`, in which case the value that you provide to it wouldn't be sufficient.  That weird edge case is one of two reasons that you get an error.

The other reason is that `Props` doesn't allow for `firebase` to be `null`, but the `Consumer` says that it could either have `Firebase` or `null`.

But 99.9% of the time it is the same thing, so it's fine to assert `{...(props as Props)}` like you have done here.  You might want to expand `Props` to allow `null`, but if you know that it's not going to be `null` in your app then it's not an issue.

You can avoid some of the errors if you let your generic `Props` represent the props without `firebase`.  Instead of dropping `firebase` from the return, we add it to the `Component`.  We `Omit` any existing definition of `firebase` from `Props` which rules out the edge case where the `Component` requires some value of `firebase` other than what we provide.

```
const withFirebase = <Props extends {}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Omit<Props, 'firebase'> & {firebase: Firebase | null}>
): ComponentType<Props> => (props) => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {(firebase) => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
```

Comment: Thanks @LindaPaiste. This sure resolved my error. It showed me where I went wrong, I have used the approach that you provided. I dropped the firebase from the component.