# How do I turn a JSX Element into a Function Component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My React app has the following in App.js:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
       ... various routes, all working fine ...
      <Route exact path={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} />}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

I'm getting an error on Dashboard, which says `JSX element type 'Dashboard' does not have any construct or call signatures`.

This is because `Dashboard` is created like this:

```
const DashboardPage = ({firebase}:DashboardProps) => {
  
  return (
    <div className="mainRoot dashboard">...contents of dashboard...</div>
  );
}

const Dashboard = withFirebase(DashboardPage);
export default Dashboard;
```

and `withFirebase` is:

import FirebaseContext  from './firebaseContext';

```
const withFirebase = (Component:any) => (props:any) => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);

export default withFirebase;
```

So withFirebase is exporting a JSX element, so that's what Dashboard is. How can I ensure that withFirebase is exporting a Component instead?

Comment: This works for me https://jsfiddle.net/rqjekw23/ so it must be an issue somewhere else.

Comment: This is a typescript error, I think you will need to specify the correct types

Comment: Not sure why but if you explicitly _return_ the JSX it works: https://jsfiddle.net/dhpqx8cb/ . Does not if you ` => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>` but does if you ` => { return (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>`

Comment: This is very strange... https://jsfiddle.net/vq0gp5rd/ this works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So withFirebase is exporting a JSX element, so that's what Dashboard is. How can I ensure that withFirebase is exporting a Component instead?

`withFirebase` is not creating a JSX element, it is creating *a function which creates a JSX Element* -- in other words that's a function component.  Perhaps it helps to type it properly.

```
const withFirebase = <Props extends {}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Omit<Props, "firebase"> & { firebase: Firebase | null }>
): React.FC<Props> => (props) => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {(firebase) => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
```

Those type are explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66093723/10431574).  Is your context value sometimes `null`?  Can your `DashboardPage` handle that, or do we need to handle it here?  Here's one way to make sure that `DashboardPage` can only be called with a valid `Firebase` prop.

```
const withFirebase = <Props extends {}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Omit<Props, "firebase"> & { firebase: Firebase }>
): React.FC<Props> => (props) => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {(firebase) =>
      firebase ? (
        <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />
      ) : (
        <div>Error Loading Firebase App</div>
      )
    }
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
```

Now that we have fixed the HOC, your `Dashboard` component has type `React.FC<{}>`.  It's a function component that does not take any props.

You do not need to create an inline `render` method for your `Route` (this will actually give errors about incompatible props).  You can set it as the `component` property `component={Dashboard}`.

complete code:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// placeholder
class Firebase {
  app: string;

  constructor() {
    this.app = "I'm an app";
  }
}

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext<Firebase | null>(null);

const withFirebase = <Props extends {}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Omit<Props, "firebase"> & { firebase: Firebase }>
): React.FC<Props> => (props) => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {(firebase) =>
      firebase ? (
        <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />
      ) : (
        <div>Error Loading Firebase App</div>
      )
    }
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);

interface DashboardProps {
  firebase: Firebase;
}

const DashboardPage = ({ firebase }: DashboardProps) => {
  console.log(firebase);
  return <div className="mainRoot dashboard">...contents of dashboard...</div>;
};

const Dashboard = withFirebase(DashboardPage);

const App = () => {
  const firebase = new Firebase();
  return (
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={firebase}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```