# React TS: Can I do this without typecasting? "could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have this code (which is a simplified version of my real code, hopefully I didn't remove anything important)

```
import React, { ReactElement, ReactNode, createElement } from "react";

interface WithChildren {
  children: ReactNode;
}

type WrapperType<WTProps> = (
  props: WithChildren & WTProps
) => ReactElement | null;

interface SetProps<P> {
  wrap: WrapperType<P>;
  children: ReactNode;
  [x: string]: unknown;
}
export function Set<WProps>(props: SetProps<WProps>) {
  const { wrap, children, ...rest } = props;

  return createElement(wrap, { ...rest, children });
}

interface WrapperProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  foo: string;
}
const ChildWrapper: React.FC<WrapperProps> = ({ foo, children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>ChildWrapper</h1>
      <p>{foo}</p>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Set wrap={ChildWrapper} foo="bar">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </Set>
  );
}
```

The `createElement` line gives this error

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ children: React.ReactNode; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attributes & WithChildren & WProps'.
      Type '{ children: React.ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'WProps'.
        'WProps' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ children: React.ReactNode; }'
```

I can "fix" it by typecasting like this

```
return createElement(wrap, { ...rest, children } as WProps & WithChildren);
```

But that removes the type safety.

I found this similar question [ts: 'Props' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66089656/ts-props-could-be-instantiated-with-an-arbitrary-type-which-could-be-unrelate) where they used `Omit<>` to fix it. But I couldn't figure out how to apply that in my case.

Is there any way to do this without typecasting?

**EDIT:** Here's a codesandbox that shows the error https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-microservice-ck7nf?file=/src/App.tsx

And a screenshot of the error message

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Seems like I haven't  got this error in your code

Comment: @zixiCat I added a codesandbox link where you can see the error

Comment: I started writing you a long answer but actually where I'm at right now the type for `children` is being inferred as the type of the children of the `Set` instead of the the children of `ChildWrapper` so `WrapperProps` would have to be `JSX.Element` instead of `ReactNode`.  https://tsplay.dev/WKkpzW  I'll see if I can control the inference better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I changed it a lot. And for why the initial code would got error, I feel a little confused about that.
Maybe `WProps` in `Set<WProps>(props: SetProps<WProps>)` can't obtain a correct initial type from instance.

My solution:

```js
import React, { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';

export function Set<WProps>(
  props: WProps & {
    wrap: (props: WProps) => ReactElement;
  }
) {
  const { wrap: Wrap } = props;
  return <Wrap {...props} />;
}

interface WrapperProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  foo: string;
}

const ChildWrapper = ({ foo, children }: WrapperProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>ChildWrapper</h1>
      <p>{foo}</p>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Set<WrapperProps> wrap={ChildWrapper} foo={'1'}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </Set>
  );
}
```

The property `strictFunctionTypes` in My `tsconfig` is set to be `false`(the default value), so I didn't reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, one of my design goals was to require all wrappers to take `children` as a prop. Here we can remove `children` from `WrapperProps` and remove support for children from `ChildWrapper` and it still compiles. That's why I had a separate `WithChildren` interface that I joined with `WTProps`. Would that be possible to enforce here?

Comment: @Tobbe: Nope, this's another question as show below, click for [more detail about this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)
_________________________________________________________________________________
`const a: (p: string) => void = () => { }; // No error thrown`

Comment: The reason that the previous code had an error and your doesn't is that `wrap` was removed from the props before, which is a potential problem if `WProps` includes `wrap`.  You are passing through the entire `props` object, which we know is assignable to `WProps`, so that fixes the error :)

Comment: Also you don't need the `<WrapperProps>` annotation inside `<Set<WrapperProps>>`.  It looks like it's getting inferred fine on it's own.